# Azure Web App Code 503 - Service Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-appservice

I'm having a problem with my 4 webapps on Azure.
All of them have "Running" status, but I cannot deploy new releases, I receive code 503 "Service Unavailable", the deploy does not complete.

My Apps run successfully on Visual Studio, I was inspecting the available logs on Azure and found this:

"[BYOS] Custom storage volume(s) failed to initialize: [/var/LWASFiles/Sites/webapp-name/a3cxxc4-116b-4ed3-9498-1fdddxxx13]".

Comment: Just to make a note that I've already restarted the webapp, but neither it works well nor I am able to create new releases. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several days back, I do have an Azure App Service running a custom container and stopped working after binding the path to Azure File Share and observer this issue at the Container Issues Logs -

`[BYOS] Custom storage volume(s) failed to initialize: [/var/LWASFiles/Sites/krishwebapp1205/d7126143-13k8-36b2-907c-0345718gxv71]`.

**I resolved by enabling the storage account networking part to all networks in the portal**.

Comment: Thank you Hari, you saved my day. I also had binding a path to Azure File Share and that was the problem.

Comment: One more note: In my case I just removed the binding path on the webapp configuration.